# Aggregation like PostgreSQL array_agg in mysql using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, innodb

Here's my code but I'm getting `null` for the field `shared_with`, any hunches?

```
shared_with = (
                query(sqlalchemy.func.group_concat(SLM.id, AC.email)).
                filter(SLM.AC_id == AC.id).
                filter(SLM.shared_list_id == SharedList.id ).
                filter(SharedList.type_code == CL.type_code)
            )
query = query(
    CL.id,
    CL.type_code,
    shared_with.label('shared_with'),

)
```